# WHERE SQL Statement Error

Tags: sql, select

My SQL doesn't work. 
Results in this error:

> 'Syntax error in string in query expression 'EmployeeName = "Charlie"
>   AND Completed = True"'.

Removing two of the speech marks at the ends changes the error to

> 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

This is my statement, the first half works, it's the `Completed = True` part that is causing the error.

```
("
Select * 
from tbl_shifts 
WHERE EmployeeName = """ & EmployeeLogin.usersname & """ AND Completed = True
", MyConn)
```

Comment: character literals (aka strings) have to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. Double quotes are for identifiers (e.g. a column name). Also which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Use single tick, not quotes. And True is probably not a valid value either.

Comment: @shawnt00 `true` *is* a valid boolean literal in standard SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cb963/1

Comment: Concatinating string is a VERY poor choice in creating SQL, your code is extremely suspetible to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) that could lead to the loss of data and security issues.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was just offering thoughts on an error without knowing the specific platform. Apparently you recognize the error messages. I did say "probably".

Answer (score 1):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`):

```
("
Select * 
from tbl_shifts 
WHERE EmployeeName = '" & EmployeeLogin.usersname & "' AND Completed = True
", MyConn)
```

Comment: I should clarify. The SQL is used to fill a datagridview upon the form loading. This is my code for the datagridview

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what datatype 'Completed' is, but I expect it's a bit. If so, you can try to pass the value 1 instead of true.

Comment: How do you know Charlie is using SQL Server? `true` **is** a valid value for a `boolean` type in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Add a " before True to make it "True"

Try also `'` (single tick) instead of `"`